# Android app built with "make project" crashes, but not when installed with "Run"

Tags: android, highcharts, android-build, dagger-hilt, android-highcharts

We're building an app which uses `HighCharts` `Android` wrapper library*.
During development, the app is installed on devices/emulators via the **Run** command, and everything works fine.

*But*, when making a build view **Make Project**, **Generate Signed APK**, or builds produced by **CI/DC Pipelines** - the app always crashes.

The crash occurs somewhere when `Highcharts` calls `Gson` (which needs to be externally provided as a dependancy for it in `Gradle` build file). `Gson` then throws a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` exception. (stacktrace below)

### what it's not:

1. Not related to Android version. tested on API's 29, 25, 23
2. Not device related. Happens on Physical devices and emulators running *clean* android.
3. Not `Proguard` related (I think) - happens also on `debug` builds, and also aggressive `keep` statements were added just to be on the safe side.
4. Same charts work properly on our website and iOS app.

### Maybe related:

`Highcharts Android` is not yet compatible with `Hilt DI`, which is deeply embedded in our code. Apparently, `Highcharst` expects the `Context` provided to it's `View` constructor to be of `Activity` type, which is broken with `Hilt` since in injects a `FragmentContextWrapper` into `Fragments` annotated with `@AndroidEntryPoint`.
[description and workaround here](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-android/issues/153)

## What I'm trying to understand:

#### What could be the difference in the output `.APK` built during *Run* and *Make*?

A full description of the crash, with example code, can be found [here](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-android/issues/154)

---

* `HighCharts` is a `JS` charting library. The `Android Highcharts` library is a `Java` wrapper for `JS` that runs on a custom `WebView`. The `API` is also `Java` Objects and functions wrapping `JS` code.

Stacktrace:

```
2020-07-30 09:39:25.679 5627-5627/com.app.android.debug E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.app.android.debug, PID: 5627
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
        at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.getGenericSupertype($Gson$Types.java:240)
        at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.getSupertype($Gson$Types.java:272)
        at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.getCollectionElementType($Gson$Types.java:290)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.create(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:52)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:423)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:56)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:97)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:208)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:208)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:208)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:208)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:669)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:648)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:603)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:583)
        at com.highsoft.highcharts.core.i.a(SourceFile:8)
        at com.highsoft.highcharts.core.f.c(SourceFile:2)
        at com.highsoft.highcharts.core.HIChartView$q0.update(SourceFile:4)
        at java.util.Observable.notifyObservers(Observable.java:163)
        at java.util.Observable.notifyObservers(Observable.java:115)
        at com.highsoft.highcharts.core.HIFoundation$a.update(SourceFile:4)
        at java.util.Observable.notifyObservers(Observable.java:163)
        at java.util.Observable.notifyObservers(Observable.java:115)
        at com.highsoft.highcharts.common.hichartsclasses.HISeries.setData(SourceFile:3)
        at com.app.android.ui.customviews.hicharts.LineGraphChart$applyDataSet$1.run(LineGraphChart.kt:256)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7397)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)
```

Comment: From Highcharts support side - as I found out your case is already consulted with our Android Wrapper creator via emails. Please continue this thread over there and later if the solution will appear please share it here - could be useful for other users. Of course, maybe the community will be able to help also.

Comment: The Highcharts is pretty popular and seems like the crash happens because of conflict with other frameworks. I would create an empty project with the Highcharts library + some mocked data

Comment: The difference could be in a signature